# Error while handling xml file in a php class

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have created a class in PHP which will handle XML files for me(using DOM). The only function of the class that I need now is 'DeleteNodes' which depends on other functions. Here's the class:

```
class HandleXML{
    public $DomElem;
    private $path;
    private $node;
    private $parent;
    private $nodes;

    function HandleXML($path){
        $this->path=$path;
        $this->DomElem=new DOMDocument();
        $this->DomElem->Load($path);

        //Default values
        $this->parent=$this->DomElem->documentElement;
    }
    function SelectNodes($tagName){
        $this->nodes=$this->DomElem->getElementsByTagName($tagName);
        return $this->nodes;
    }
    function SelectNodeById($id){
        $this->node=$this->nodes->item($id);
        //return $this->node;
    }
    function DeleteNode(){
        $this->node->parentNode->removeChild($this->node);  //Line 91-here's the error
    }
    function DeleteNodes(){
        for ($i=$this->nodes->length; $i >=0 ; $i--) { 
            $this->SelectNodeById($i);
            $this->DeleteNode();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how I handle the class(from another PHP page):

```
$file=new HandleXML("../Data files/XML Data/Data.xml");

$file->SelectNodes("announce");
$file->DeleteNodes();
```

and this is the Data.xml file(in another language):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<information>
    <announce>
        <picture>calendar.png</picture>
        <text>Anunt in vederea inscrierii in clasa V - a</text>
    </announce>
    <announce>
        <picture>Janitor.png</picture>
        <text>Anunt in vedera angajarii unui ingrijitor</text>
</information>
```

The error says: "Trying to get property of a non-Object on line 91". It seems like the variable $node hasn't been set by 'SelectNodeById' function in the for loop. Why is that?

Comment: What do you get with `gettype($this->node)` and `var_dump($this->node)` ?

Comment: @frz3993 NULL and NULL. It's just like the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you put that in the for loop inside the `DeleteNodes` method?

Comment: `for ($i=$this->nodes->length -1;` and btw: The name `SelectNodeById` is misleading, it's more like `SelectNodeByPositionInNodeListe`.

Comment: Yes. I decommented 'return $this->node' from SelectNodeById and then in the loop 'return var_dump($this->SelectNodeById($i))' and in the other file echo $file->DelteNodes. This is only for a node.

Comment: It works. Thank you! It seems there was no node with the index position length. It started from 0 so...You should post it as  an answer.

Comment: Yes , indeed , that's the problem;